# Teradata Fastload Script Issue - Date not properly formatted error 2665

Tags: sql, datetime, teradata

I have a fastload script that is giving me problems. I am new to teradata and don't know how the date should be properly formatted. the date column is currently formatted as :"12/31/2011" in excel (csv).

My script is as follows:

```
BEGIN LOADING "table"
    ERRORFILES "errors1", "errors2";


SET RECORD VARTEXT ",";


DEFINE PERD_END_RPT_DT   (VARCHAR(20)),  <---- date column returning the error
       RPT_PERD_TYPE_CD  (VARCHAR(20)),
       PERD_NM       (VARCHAR(30)),
       QTR_NUM           (VARCHAR(2)),
       YEAR_NUM          (VARCHAR(4)),
       RPT_PERD_TYPE_NM  (VARCHAR(10)),
       DATA_VLDTN_IND    (VARCHAR(1)),
       EDW_PUBLN_ID      (VARCHAR(18)) 

FILE=C:\pathtofile\file.csv;

INSERT INTO "table" ( PERD_END_RPT_DT, RPT_PERD_TYPE_CD, PERD_NM, QTR_NUM, YEAR_NUM, RPT_PERD_TYPE_NM,
                          DATA_VLDTN_IND, EDW_PUBLN_ID )
    VALUES ( :PERD_END_RPT_DT, :RPT_PERD_TYPE_CD, :PERD_NM, :QTR_NUM, :YEAR_NUM, :RPT_PERD_TYPE_NM,
                          :DATA_VLDTN_IND, :EDW_PUBLN_ID ) ;

END LOADING ;
LOGOFF ;
```

So how should the date be formatted and how can I modify my script to make it work? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the data type of the underlying column PERD_END_RPT_TD? Judging by the length alone it seems to me to be a TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Furthermore, what is the format of the incoming data in the field :PERD_END_RPRT_DT?

Comment: The incoming format is "9/30/2011" or "12/1/2011". And it is a Date format in a teradata db.

Comment: I am importing from a .csv excel file. When i change the format in excel to default or general it changes the date to just a 5 or 6 digit number. I am going to try importing as that and see if it gets formatted to the correct date in the db.

Comment: So some research has turned up a solution that looks something like this: VALUES ( :PERD_END_RPT_DT (Date, Format 'mm/dd/yyyy'), ....but this also returned the same error. Is this atleast on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BEGIN LOADING "table"
    ERRORFILES "errors1", "errors2";


SET RECORD VARTEXT ",";


DEFINE PERD_END_RPT_DT   (VARCHAR(20)),  -- date column returning the error
       RPT_PERD_TYPE_CD  (VARCHAR(20)),
       PERD_NM           (VARCHAR(30)),
       QTR_NUM           (VARCHAR(2)),
       YEAR_NUM          (VARCHAR(4)),
       RPT_PERD_TYPE_NM  (VARCHAR(10)),
       DATA_VLDTN_IND    (VARCHAR(1)),
       EDW_PUBLN_ID      (VARCHAR(18)) 

FILE=C:\pathtofile\file.csv;

INSERT INTO "table" ( PERD_END_RPT_DT, RPT_PERD_TYPE_CD, PERD_NM, QTR_NUM, YEAR_NUM, RPT_PERD_TYPE_NM, DATA_VLDTN_IND, EDW_PUBLN_ID )
    VALUES ( CAST(:PERD_END_RPT_DT AS DATE FORMAT 'mm/dd/yyyy') -- Changed here
           , :RPT_PERD_TYPE_CD
           , :PERD_NM
           , :QTR_NUM'
           , :YEAR_NUM
           , :RPT_PERD_TYPE_NM 
           , :DATA_VLDTN_IND
           , :EDW_PUBLN_ID ) ;

END LOADING ;
LOGOFF ;
```

Comment: Fastload does not allow the use of expressions in INSERT. I am making a multiload script to try this and another option I discovered

Comment: Forgot about that. I tested the SQL for the conversion but not the FastLoad script. (Admittedly rusty on my FastLoad scripting)

Comment: I'm going to have to mock up something. I don't write FastLoad scripts often enough to know offhand what it will take to make this work. MultiLoad does give more flexibility but at a slight trade off for speed.